Have vertical overflow work without explicity setting height
I have a table table which is made out of 3 parts

the header
the content
the footer
With flexbox, I've made it so that the "content" section takes up all of the available view height but this isn't done explicitly so that when there are too many items in "content" the page itself will expand instead of the "content" section overflowing.

I want the "content" to still take up all the available view height without overflowing the page itself and instead overflowing the "content" section thus creating a scroll area
content section:
<code>
<div class="flex flex-col flex-1 text-sm text-[#707070] overflow-scroll" :class="csvData ? '' : 'justify-center items-center'">

<!-- Table body -->
    <div v-if="csvData" v-for="(row, index) in filteredData" :key="index" class="grid items-center gap-4 px-2 py-4 grid-cols-[auto,1fr,1fr,1fr] sm:grid-cols-[auto,1fr,1fr,1fr,1fr] md:grid-cols-[auto,1fr,1fr,1fr,1fr,1fr]">
        <input @click="toggleRow(index)" :disabled=" enableEditMode ? true : false" type="checkbox" v-model="selectedRows[index]">
        <span>Unassigned</span>
        <span role="textbox" :class="row.editMode ? 'border p-1 border-dashed border-[#606069]' : '' " >{{ row.editedData[0] }}</span>
        <span role="textbox" :class="row.editMode ? 'border p-1 border-dashed border-[#606069]' : '' " >{{ row.editedData[1] }}</span>
        <span role="textbox" :class="row.editMode ? 'border p-1 border-dashed border-[#606069]' : '' " class="hidden md:block" >{{ row.editedData[2] }}</span>
        <span role="textbox" :class="row.editMode ? 'border p-1 border-dashed border-[#606069]' : '' " class="hidden sm:block" >{{ row.editedData[3] }}</span>
    </div>
</div>

</code>
A scrollable area is created in the content section without overflowing the page.
As you can see here it currently overflows the page and doesn't show the footer.


You'd want to give the parent container that holds the header, footer, and the content area a set height of 100vh. That will keep the parent at the height of the browser window - once that's done the rest should behave as expected

Try out this code
<div class="flex flex-col flex-1 text-sm text-[#707070]">
<!-- Table body -->
<div class="overflow-auto">
    <div v-if="csvData" v-for="(row, index) in filteredData" :key="index" class="grid items-center gap-4 px-2 py-4 grid-cols-[auto,1fr,1fr,1fr] sm:grid-cols-[auto,1fr,1fr,1fr,1fr] md:grid-cols-[auto,1fr,1fr,1fr,1fr,1fr]">
        <input @click="toggleRow(index)" :disabled="enableEditMode ? true : false" type="checkbox" v-model="selectedRows[index]">
        <span>Unassigned</span>
        <span role="textbox" :class="row.editMode ? 'border p-1 border-dashed border-[#606069]' : '' ">{{ row.editedData[0] }}</span>
        <span role="textbox" :class="row.editMode ? 'border p-1 border-dashed border-[#606069]' : '' ">{{ row.editedData[1] }}</span>
        <span role="textbox" :class="row.editMode ? 'border p-1 border-dashed border-[#606069]' : '' " class="hidden md:block">{{ row.editedData[2] }}</span>
        <span role="textbox" :class="row.editMode ? 'border p-1 border-dashed border-[#606069]' : '' " class="hidden sm:block">{{ row.editedData[3] }}</span>
    </div>
</div>


hi! thank you for responding! adding a div around with overflow-auto still expands the page instead of the container itself!
my code is like this
header
content
footer
and what ive shown in the post is the footer
